# Wait for vsix to finish installation before launching visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, batch-file, command-line, visual-studio-extensions

I'm installing some vsix extensions in silent mode using visual studio command line

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"

VSIXInstaller.exe /q ABC.vsix

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

My problem is that Visual Studio is launched before the vsix finishes installing.

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to wait before starting up.

I don't want to use a timer, because the number of vsix to install is unknown to me.

`EDIT` Based on **Alastair Campbell** response

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"

start /wait VSIXInstaller.exe /q ABC.vsix

start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

I added start without /wait in the last line, otherwise the command line won't close, and it will wait for visual studio to be closed before closing itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible using the `START` command.

```
START /WAIT VSIXInstaller.exe /q "C:\Developpement\ABC.vsix"
```

Calling the `START` command with the help parameter, this is one of the lines in the output:

```
WAIT        Start application and wait for it to terminate.
```

Here is the batch script I used to test:

```
@ECHO OFF
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"
ECHO Loaded VS Command Line...
START /WAIT VSIXInstaller.exe /q VsVim.vsix
START /WAIT VSIXInstaller.exe /q AxTools.VS10X.CodeMap.vsix
START /WAIT VSIXInstaller.exe /q CodeMaid_v0.7.3.vsix
START /WAIT VSIXInstaller.exe /q ProPowerTools.vsix
ECHO DONE
START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
PAUSE
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I tried it and visual studio started before. In my case, only 2/5 extensions have been installed.

Comment: What is `call "C:\...\vcvarsall.bat"` doing? And did you make all of the VSIXInstaller.exe lines `START /WAIT`?

Comment: The `vcvarsall.bat` is the Visual Studio Developer Command line. Without it I can't use `VSIXInstaller`. And yes I added START /WAIT for all the line where I have VSIXInstaller.

Comment: I just tested this with Visual Studio 2013 and it worked perfectly without issue. I have posted the exact batch file I used to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, it's working know. I had a problem in one of the vsix files.

Comment: You have to add and empty string in the title like what I did. Otherwise, it will open another command line in a separate window.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that but wasn't really too concerned to fix it. I could tell that everything was being installed correctly. All the same, I will fix it so people can copy the answer later.